# OpenGL Shader Info Results errors

Tags: opengl, shader

I'm using glew on Windows 7, and when I call:

```
int compileResult = 0;
int infoLogLength = 0;
//compile code
glGetShaderiv(_vertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileResult);
glGetShaderiv(_vertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
GLchar vInfoLogMessage[512];
glGetShaderInfoLog(_vertexShaderID, infoLogLength, NULL, vInfoLogMessage);
```

I had to hardcode the 512 because the **infoLogLength** is always returning 0. I googled it and found to be a bug on Android that happens sometimes, but I'm not using the Android SDK/NDK...
And even with that, **vInfoLogMessage** is not being filled with info at all, either success or failure.

**compileResult** however shows as being successfully compiled, but I'd like to be able to get info if it fails.

What could be causing this?

**edit**: <strike>The program linking returns an error, but I can't get it because it's not filling the infoLogMessage...</strike>
This was an error of mine, it's returning as successful as well.

The codes of the shaders, if relevant, are:

```
//fragmentShader
#version 330 core
out vec3 color;
void main()
{
    color = vec3(1, 0, 0);
}

//vertexShader
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
void main()
{
    gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: What does the compile result tells you?

Comment: It's returning as successful (1), but I don't get anything about the infoLog at all, neither the length (always returns 0), neither the message (never fills the char array). From some tutorials I've seen, it's supposed to return successful messages as well.

Comment: Does it return a non-zero length when you have an error? Your driver just might not have anything to say about valid shaders.

Comment: It returns 0 when I have an error, and then the InfoLength was properly fixed! I thought it was supposed to return something always and this was bugging me! Thanks!